# how to block imports of a javascript file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, import

how can I "block" imports of a javascript file?

ex: if the file is:

```js
const file = require('./file');
```

or

```js
import file from './file';
```

would it be possible to make sure that if there were any of these two forms of import, the file would give an error or would it just not work?
ps: i still want to be able to export

Comment: Are these files part of a build process, and you want the build process to error if files inside of certain folders have import or require?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve/prevent by this? This sounds like an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @TKoL Yes, it is

Comment: @ChrisG this is the problem x, I do not want that file to have access to the folders of the directory through require or import

Comment: Please be more specific about the circumstances here; why are strangers adding files to your build process?

Comment: @ChrisG why exactly would I have to say that? I didn't put this in order not to make the question complicated, it is simple to understand, I need a way to block imports, that's all, it could be some code in the same file

Comment: @ChrisG ok, i'll tell you what i'm doing, i'm creating a disc for bot that executes js commands from what you wrote, some commands can make the person see the project code or even manage to delete some files, or rename them or others stuff
I want to isolate the file, that's all.

Comment: A discord bot? I'm still not sure i understand; either it runs on your own server, which means nothing of the source code is accessible in any way, and you'll be processing user commands, i.e. single lines of text. Or you put it on github for other people to use for their own server, in which case why would you have to block imports? -- I don't know how a discord command would enable people to access or delete server files? How exactly would that work? And why would you need to block imports to prevent that?

Comment: @ChrisG why do i have to explain the whole project to you? the only thing i wanted to know is written. You don't need to know my whole project to understand the problem I want to solve, as I said several times, I just want to isolate the file.

Comment: man, it was such a simple thing and you made it so complicated

Comment: Isolating a source file during the build process is not a "simple thing". If it were, we'd simply tell you how to do it. I'm still 99% sure that your question is an xy problem, unless your discord users are uploading JS source files somewhere, and telling your bot to recompile, redeploy and restart itself.

Comment: @ChrisG but this is exactly what I wanted to do

Comment: That is really unsafe though, you would have to block all kinds of functions in that case, like http.* and fs.* for instance. The only solution I can see is to run the bot in a sandbox and only allow it to communicate with the discord server. You would need to deploy it to a virtualbox for instance, then firewall it.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a custom made hook where you could have access to all of the file content and upon that to decide to strip or to load the file but the logic could be quite tangled and complicated if you want to create and common approach. You could read more about [custom hooks](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/hooking-into-node-loader-for-fun-and-profit/) and decide for yourself if this approach is suitable for you.